# Git rebase in Visual Studio Code

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

Here is my situation: I have a production branch, a dev branch and branches for features. While I was working on a feature I has to do a hotfix on the dev branch. Now I to rebase the feature branch I am currently working on to avoid future merging conflicts. When I used to use IDEs from JetBrain I would do a git rebase and it would do the trick. The only command I found in VSCode is Git: Sync(rebase) but this does not do anything and does not rebase. All I get is this message:

```
This action will push and pull commit to and from 'origin/Current_feature'
```

Anyone have experience with this?

Comment: It sounds like “Git: Sync (rebase)” does `git pull --rebase`, as a companion to “Git: Sync”, which might do a plain `git pull`. `git pull --rebase` rebases new commits on the branch instead of merging them.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I don't think Visual Studio Code has Git rebase functionality built-in. If you want to do your rebasing in Visual Studio Code instead with the `git` command-line tool or with a [Git GUI](https://git-scm.com/downloads/guis), you can install the **[GitLens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens)** extension for VS Code.

[GitLens’s README](https://github.com/eamodio/vscode-gitlens#repository-view) indicates that GitLens supports rebasing. It says that when viewing branches, the context menu for each branch includes these commands:

- *Rebase (Interactive) Branch (via Terminal)*
- *Rebase (Interactive) Branch to Remote (via Terminal)*

And when viewing the commits in one branch, the context menu for each commit includes this command:

- *Rebase to Commit (via Terminal)* (when available)

Comment: As of 2020, this functionality does exist; see Marc Aurel's answer on this same page: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64806766/2327879

Answer (score 27):

I just tried, it works!! [image]

PS: I try to find the approach to setting the default "Sync" action with `--rebase` paramter. I find the PR of [Added config option to sync+Rebase from statusbar](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/pull/52646), but it haven't landed.

Finally find the solution,  `git config --global pull.rebase true` and it works!!

Comment: You can now Sync+Rebase since September2018 release https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_28#_always-rebase-when-running-sync

Comment: This wrapper for `git pull --rebase` provides a way to rebase while pulling (that is, to fetch and then rebase on the remote branch), but not a way to rebase `HEAD` on an arbitrary commit.

Comment: This only rebases your local commits on top of new pulled-in commits in the same branch. It doesn't allow rebasing on another branch (such as `git rebase origin/master`), which I think is what OP was asking. I'm still not sure if vscode has a non-terminal way to rebase on another branch.

Answer (score 19):

You could run the command directly from your terminal with:
`git rebase branch` or `git rebase -i branch`

You will have to configure your gitconfig to use vscode for the interactive rebase.

Something like:

```
[core]
  editor = code --wait
```

Or by setting your envar to `GIT_EDITOR=code\ --wait`

As soon as you want to do something a bit out of the ordinary, using the command line yield better results.

Comment: This fixed my problem! I had only "edit = code" and when doing `git rebase -i origin/master` vscode did the rebase automatically ...

Answer (score 9):

Since VS Code 1.51 (October 2020) a command named "*Git: Rebase branch...*" (`git.rebase`) has been added: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_51#_git-rebase-command

Comment: This is the correct answer! 

From your feature branch:

hit `F1` -> `Git: Rebase branch...` -> select the develop branch (main branch).

Done.

Answer (score 9):

Looks like this VS Code PR introduced a new `git.rebaseWhenSync` option:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/52527

[image]

I tested it and it looks like it works as expected.

Answer (score 4):

You can set the [git config](https://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration) to automatically open VSCode for rebases like this:

```
git config --global core.editor code
```

Then you can simply rebase with this command:

```
git rebase -i name-of-branch
```

[image]

*Note 1:* In order to have the nice formatting like shown on the screenshot, you'll need to install [GitLens](https://open-vsx.org/extension/eamodio/gitlens).

*Note 2:* If you are using [VSCodium](https://vscodium.com/), you should configure git to use it instead:

```
git config --global core.editor codium
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems that in the recent version of VSCode you can do Pull+Rebase like this:

[image]