# Is there a simpler way to handle git conflicts in VSCode

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, merge, fetch, pull

I'm currently trying figure out Trunk Based Development with another team member:

Both of us are pushing directly to `origin/master`

When my teammate pushes, the repo in VSCode's `Source Control Repositories` will indicate I can `Pull 1 commits from origin/master`

Assuming we have modified the same file, clicking on the indicator will pop up a message: `Please clean your repository working tree before checkout.`

Right now, it's cumbersome as I have to stash away my changes, pull and then pop the stash etc and I'm not even certain if I lost any changes

My main question here is, how can I bring up the Merge Conflict Editor to deal with this. I tried googling, but wasn't able to find out how this could be done

Any ideas?

Comment: Something like [Pull (rebase)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52235380/7034621) should help.

Comment: Thanks! That finally brought up the Merge Conflict Editor. Let's say in step 3, my teammate modified the same file as me + added another file. It seems weird that VSCode attributes the new file to me. Is there a way to recognize all my teammate's changes, then use the merge editor to merge in my changes?

Comment: I thought that's what Pull (rebase) will do, re-apply all your changes on top of the latest revision from upstream (`origin/master` I assume). Are you sure you're not stuck in some rebase limbo? After resolving the conflicts you probably need to `Git: rebase (continue)`.

Comment: @orhtej2 yes, my bad. It is behaving as I want it now. Thank you!!

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67624690/11107541

Answer (score 1):

The (better) way I wanted to handle the conflict is known as `Pull (Rebase)` as mentioned by @orhtej2 (Thanks!), meaning, `pulling` down all the changes from `origin/master` and `rebasing` our changes on top of it

Assuming that the `origin/master` is ahead of me, the exact steps would be as follows:

1. Commit my changes locally first
2. `Source Control` in VSCode will display the button `Sync changes 1⬇ 1⬆`
3. Go to the `…` of `Source Control` and click on `Pull (Rebase)`
4. `Source Control` will list out the files that it does not know how to handle
5. Clicking on any of the files will bring it up with the option to use the `Merge Conflict Editor`
6. When all files are deconflicted (`merged`), go to `Source Control` and click on `Continue`
7. That will push your deconflicted files to the `origin/master`